# How do I load data from a database and display it on a webpage?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, webforms

I have a complete form that saves inputs into a SQL Server database. Now I want to display old records in that same page inside the textboxes. I have made a text box and a load button that I would like to enter a Job Number into and it displays that row of data from the db. I am using C# for the code behind, and other than that I am not sure what info you need. Any help is welcome and appreciated. This is my first project with coding outside of batch files so I am a blank canvas.

[image: Web Form all asp tags]

Comment: Which part are you actually stuck on? Do you know how to query data from the database using C#? Do you know how to get data from your application's memory into the text boxes? Have you picked a method of accessing the data such as ADO.NET, Dapper, or Entity Framework?

Comment: Hey, welcome to the site! For us to help you out, we need some more information from you so we can understand your problem better. It might help out if you edit your question and phrase it like "here is my problem, here is what I tried to fix it, and here is where I am stuck on."

Comment: Like I said I am new to this. I have the form saving textbox values into the table but getting it to see the "Job Number" and load that row of data is a new can of worms. I just dont want to use a datagridview. Just thought it would be the same concept of using the code behind page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, basic flow here:

1. Set up your **Connection String** (defines what database server to connect to, what username/password to use, what specific database on the server to look at). See https://www.connectionstrings.com/
2. Declare and Initialize the necessary objects:

   - a **Connection** object using your connection string from a second ago;
   - a **Command** object to tell the database what data to pull out through the connection; and
   - a **Data Reader** to load the actual record data into, which can then be used in the code-behind to populate the fields.
3. Read the data to the page.

As an example, consider the following code:

```
using System.Data.SQLClient
```

. . .

```
string ConString = "Server=localhost\\SQLEXPRESS2017;Initial Catalog=MyDatabaseName;User=DatabaseUser;Password=SomeSecretPassword;";

SqlConnection conn;
SqlCommand cmd;
SqlDataReader rdr;

conn = new SqlConnection(ConString);
conn.Open();

cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT Field1, Field2 FROM TableName WHERE Field3=@0;", conn);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@0", txtJobNo.Text); // This prevents SQL Injection

rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

if (rdr.HasRows)
{
    rdr.Read();

    txtField1.Text = rdr.GetString(0);
    txtField2.Text = rdr.GetString(1);

} else
{
    // Some custom error handling for JobID not found
}

rdr.Close();
conn.Close();
```

Of course, this will need to be tailored to your situation (Connection String, Field names, etc.)

Comment: This would be the code for the button it looks like.. Is that right? I also have that textbox for entering of the job. If that is in the code where is it? I am going to fill in these blanks and see where I am.. I appreciate it.

Comment: >_<  Argh... rusty on me C# mate... see updated answer.

Comment: And yes, this would be the code to fire for a "Load Record" button of some sort.  If I'm understanding your other question, you could have one textbox control for entering/editing the JobNo field, and use another for the search/load function. Just make sure they have different IDs and you're all good.

Comment: Just found another error in my code, needed `, conn` added to the statement for initializing `cmd`

Comment: Alright, I dont see where that ,conn goes into initializing cmd.    
 rdr=cmd.ExecuteReader(); is what you are talking about correct

Comment: See the answer above.  It's on the line beginning with `cmd = ...`

Comment: pffft. I see now. You edited it in. Code has no errors but it doesn't post results back into the page.. Maybe I am misunderstanding

Comment: Are you using a `Response.Redirect` *after* this code is run?  If you step through the code in debug, what do you see when you examine the `.Text` values right after they're set?

Comment: No to the redirect. I use one when I submit the form. But I assumed that if I added that it would just return a blank page. As for the rest of that I am not seeing anything, then again I am new to all of this so.

Comment: A problem I am having is tying that load button to the search bar. I want the button to see the LoaderJobNumber textbox value and find that value in the table to post that row of data into the existing textboxes. My thinking was on line 7 "Select... from table name Where LoaderJobNumber=@0". is that the purpose of that where?

Comment: Your `WHERE` statement should specify *which* table field to filter on, that way the database knows which record to return. The line right after that (8) provides the actual _value_, as given in the `LoaderJobNumber` textbox (the one you type right before hitting the button. You need to have something like: `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@0", LoaderJobNumber.Text);`

Comment: Gotcha.. Guess now I need to learn about this. System.IndexOutOfRangeException

Comment: David, I want to thank you for your help. This solved my problem. Form is up and running.. Still working on altering the saved values with new ones to see if i can do updates, but it is running so thank you.

Comment: You're certainly welcome!  To do the save, you'd need to do another command string to something like: `UPDATE TableName SET Field1=@0, Field2=@1 WHERE JobNo=@2;` and then parameterize each respective textbox input like I did the one above. Also, you would *NOT* execute a reader to save the changes, just call `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();`

Comment: David... How is this? Also.. what do i replace the rdr with? Update doesn't take.                    cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE BlockReport(Job#, PO#, Supplier, RecievedBy

Comment: You need to use `UPDATE` syntax, not `INSERT` syntax. So, `cmd = New SqlCommand("UPDATE BlockReport SET [Job#]=@0, [PO#]=@1...WHERE [Job#]=@2");`  Don't use a reader.  Just set up your command, and once you've parameterized it, call the method `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();` and the database should be updated.  Worth mentioning, anytime you have non-alphanumeric characters in field names or table names, you generally need to use brackets (square ones: `[]`) to encapsulate the names or you'll get colorful errors. Better idea: don't use symbols in field or table names.

Comment: I posted my update code in a new answer. Seeing an issue with UPDATE